# Removing max and min elements of array from mean calculation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I am hoping to delete the highest number and the lowest number from the array 3*4. Let's say, the data looks like this:

```
a=np.array([[1,4,5,10],[2,6,5,0],[3,9,9,0]])
```

so I expected to see the result like this:
    deleted_data=[4,5],[2,5],[3]

Could you advise me how to delete the max and min from each array?

---

to do so, I did like this (UPDATE):

```
#to find out the max / min values:
b = np.max(a,1) #max
c = np.min(a,1) #min

#creating dataset after deleting max & min
d=(a!=b[:,None]) & (a!=c[:,None]) 
f=[i[j] for i,j in zip(a, d)]

output: [array([8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8]), array([8, 7, 8, 6, 8, 8]), array([9, 8, 9, 9, 8]), array([6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7]), array([7, 7, 7, 7, 6])]
```

Now I am not sure how to calculate the mean of the list objects? 
I would like to calculate the mean of each array, so I have tried this:

```
mean1=f.mean(axis=0)
```

but it did not work.

Comment: @hpaulj I am a python beginner so I just had no idea how to delete the maximum values.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you? If so, consider accepting one of those?

Comment: Sorry! I was not familiar with this website. And yes, I accepted the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method is to use a [Masked Array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.html)

```
import numpy.ma as ma

mask = np.logical_or(a == a.max(1, keepdims = 1), a == a.min(1, keepdims = 1))
a_masked = ma.masked_array(a, mask = mask)
```

from there if you want an average of the unmasked elements you can just do

```
a_masked.mean()
```

Or you could even do the mean of the rows

```
a_masked.mean(1).data
```

or columns (strange, but seems to be what you're asking for)

```
a_masked.mean(0).data
```

Comment: Repeating my comment form below: The only advantage of Masked Arrays is clarity. Creating an intermediate array will almost always be slower and more memory-intensive than in-line calculations like below, and when they aren't (i.e. you want to do a lot of different operations on a heavily masked array) `scipy.sparse` arrays will be even better.

Answer (score 1):

A python `list` has a `remove` method.

With a utility function we could remove the min and max elements from a row:

```
def foo(i,j,k):
    il = i.tolist()
    il.remove(j)
    il.remove(k)
    return il

In [230]: [foo(i,j,k) for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c)]
Out[230]: [[4, 5], [2, 5], [3, 9]]
```

This could be turned back into an array with `np.array(...)`.  Note that this removed just one of the `9` in the last row.  If it had removed both, the last list would have just 1 value, and the result could not be turned back into a 2d array.

I'm sure we could come up with a pure-array method, possibly useing `argmax` and `argmin` instead of `max` and `min`.  But I think the list approach is a better starting point for a Python beginner.

---

An array masking approach

```
In [232]: bi = np.argmax(a,1)
In [233]: ci = np.argmin(a,1)
In [234]: bi
Out[234]: array([3, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [235]: ci
Out[235]: array([0, 3, 3], dtype=int32)

In [243]: mask = np.ones_like(a, bool)
In [244]: mask[np.arange(3),bi]=False
In [245]: mask[np.arange(3),ci]=False
In [246]: mask
Out[246]: 
array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [247]: a[mask]
Out[247]: array([4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 9])
In [248]: _.reshape(3,-1)
Out[248]: 
array([[4, 5],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 9]])
```

Again this is better if we just delete one max and one min from each row.

---

Another masking approach:

```
In [257]: (a!=b[:,None]) & (a!=c[:,None])
Out[257]: 
array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [258]: a[(a!=b[:,None]) & (a!=c[:,None])]
Out[258]: array([4, 5, 2, 5, 3])
```

This does remove all '9's in the last row.  But it does not preserve the row split.

This preserves the row structure, and allows variable lengths:

```
In [259]: mask=(a!=b[:,None]) & (a!=c[:,None])
In [260]: [i[j] for i,j in zip(a, mask)]
Out[260]: [array([4, 5]), array([2, 5]), array([3])]
```

Comment: This works! I used this code:
b = np.max(a,1) #max
print(b)

c = np.min(a,1) #min
print(c)
d=(a!=b[:,None]) & (a!=c[:,None]) 
f=[i[j] for i,j in zip(a, d)]
but the result shows like this as the list object: [array([8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8]), array([8, 7, 8, 6, 8, 8]), array([9, 8, 9, 9, 8]), array([6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7]), array([7, 7, 7, 7, 6])]. How can I calculate the mean of the list object?

Answer (score 1):

As @hpaulj predicted, there is an array-only method.  And it's a doozy.  As a one-liner:

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], np.sort(np.argpartition(a, (0,-1), axis = 1)[:, 1:-1], axis = 1)]
```

Let's break that down:

```
y_ = np.argpartition(a, (0,-1), axis = 1)[:, 1:-1]
```

`argpartiton` takes the index of the `0`th (smallest) and `-1`th (largest) elements of each row and moves them to the first and last position repsectively.  `[:,1:-1]` indexes everything else.  Now `argpartition` can sometimes reorder the rest of the elements, so

```
y = np.sort(y_ , axis = 1)
```

We sort the rest of the indices back to their orginal positions.  Now we have a `y.shape -> (m, n-2)` array of indices with the max and min removed, for your original `(m, n) = a.shape` array.

Now to use this, we need the row indicies as well.

```
x = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None]
```

`arange` just gives the `m` row indices. To broadcast this `x.shape -> (a.shape[0],) -> (m,)` array to your index array, you need the `[:, None]` to make `x.shape -> (m, 1)`.  Now the `m` lines up for broadcasting and you have your two sets of indices.

```
a[x, y]

array([[4, 5],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 9]])
```

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel F But this only deleted one highest and lowest. How can I delete every highest and lowest?

Comment: what do you mean by "every" highest and lowest?

Comment: as you can see there are two 9 in [3,9,9,0].

Comment: If you have multiple max and min values, there's no safe way to assure you have the same number of columns in each row after the deletion, and `numpy` is not really appropriate (as 'ragged' arrays are prety useless).  The list comprehension answer of @hpaulj would work better, unless you feel like digging into [Masked Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could get to the *final destination* of average of elements that are not the `max` or `min` per row in two steps with masking -

```
In [140]: a  # input array
Out[140]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  5, 10],
       [ 2,  6,  5,  0],
       [ 3,  9,  9,  0]])

In [141]: m = (a!=a.min(1,keepdims=1)) & (a!=a.max(1,keepdims=1))

In [142]: (a*m).sum(1)/m.sum(1).astype(float)
Out[142]: array([ 4.5,  3.5,  3. ])
```

This avoids the mess of creating the intermediate ragged arrays, which arent the most convenient data formats to operate with NumPy funcs.

Alternatively, for performance boost, use `np.einsum` to get the equivalent of `(a*m).sum(1)` with `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,m)`.

Runtime test on bigger array -

```
In [181]: np.random.seed(0)

In [182]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,(5000,5000))

# @Daniel F' soln from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325431/
In [183]: %%timeit
     ...: mask = np.logical_or(a == a.max(1, keepdims = 1), a == a.min(1, keepdims = 1))
     ...: a_masked = ma.masked_array(a, mask = mask)
     ...: out = a_masked.mean(1).data
1 loop, best of 3: 251 ms per loop

# Posted in here
In [184]: %%timeit
     ...: m = (a!=a.min(1,keepdims=1)) & (a!=a.max(1,keepdims=1))
     ...: out = (a*m).sum(1)/m.sum(1).astype(float)
10 loops, best of 3: 165 ms per loop

# Posted in here with additional einsum
In [185]: %%timeit
     ...: m = (a!=a.min(1,keepdims=1)) & (a!=a.max(1,keepdims=1))
     ...: out = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,m)/m.sum(1).astype(float)
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop
```

Comment: True.  The only advantage of Masked Arrays is clarity.  Creating an intermediate array will almost always be slower and more memory-intensive than in-line calculations like above and when they aren't (i.e. you want to do a lot of different operations on a heavily masked array) `scipy.sparse` arrays will be even better.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is to remove min and/or max elements from a numpy array `arr` then this is the easiest way in my opinion.

```
np.delete(arr, np.argmax(arr))
```

example

```
tmp = np.random.random(3)
print(tmp)

tmp = np.delete(tmp, np.argmax(tmp))
print(tmp)
```

returns

```
[0.7366768  0.65492774 0.93632866]
[0.7366768  0.65492774]
```